# C# WinForm Upcounter to hh:mm:ss

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I want to Write a Program like OBS Studio and i wanna add an Upcounter to my Program so that means when i click "Start Stream" it should start the Upcounter from 00:00:00 to 00:00:01 then to 00:00:02 and so on so that i have the "Livetime", how long i am already streaming. And with the "End Stream" Button the Timer should Stop and Reset. How can i do that?

i tried different things but dont had an idea.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace StreamManagement
{
    public partial class MainFormProgram : Form
    {
        public static bool chat_on = true;
        TimeSpan testTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
        public MainFormProgram()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void chatOnBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnLbl.Text = "ON";
            OnLbl.ForeColor = Color.ForestGreen;
            chatOnBtn.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
            chatOffBtn.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        }

        private void chatOffBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnLbl.Text = "OFF";
            OnLbl.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed;
            chatOffBtn.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
            chatOnBtn.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnLbl.Text = "ON";
            OnLbl.ForeColor = Color.ForestGreen;
            EmoteonlyOnOff.Text = "OFF";
            EmoteonlyOnOff.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed;
            SubchatOnOff.Text = "OFF";
            SubchatOnOff.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed;
        }

        private void EmoteOnlyOnBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EmoteonlyOnOff.Text = "ON";
            EmoteonlyOnOff.ForeColor = Color.ForestGreen;
            EmoteOnlyOnBtn.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(112, 147, 252);
            EmoteOnlyOffBtn.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(50, 100, 150);
        }

        private void EmoteOnlyOffBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EmoteonlyOnOff.Text = "OFF";
            EmoteonlyOnOff.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed;
            EmoteOnlyOffBtn.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(112, 147, 252);
            EmoteOnlyOnBtn.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(50, 100, 150);
        }

        private void SubChatOnBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SubchatOnOff.Text = "ON";
            SubchatOnOff.ForeColor = Color.ForestGreen;
            SubChatOnBtn.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 94, 255);
            SubChatOffBtn.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(192, 0, 192);
        }

        private void SubChatOffBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SubchatOnOff.Text = "OFF";
            SubchatOnOff.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed;
            SubChatOffBtn.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 94, 255);
            SubChatOnBtn.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(192, 0, 192);
        }

        private void startstreamBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timerXD.Start();
        }

        private void timerXD_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timerLbl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The Timer should be printed out in a label

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Stopwatch` class from `System.Diagnostics` namespace for that purpose.

Create a `Stopwatch` field in your `Form` class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch(); // <-- this one
}
```

Create a `Label` (`lblTime` for example), to which we would set upcounted time and a `Button` at your Form, which would start `Stopwatch` (`btnStart` for example):

[image]

*Optionally* you may add other `Button`s to manipulate with `Stopwatch`:

[image]

Add `Click` handler (`ButtonStart_Click` for example) to "START" button to run Stopwatch from there. Mark it with `async` to prevent `Form` freezes while `Stopwatch` running:

```
private async void ButtonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    stopwatch.Start();

    while (stopwatch.IsRunning)
    {
        lblTime.Text = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");
        await Task.Delay(1000); // Delay between time updates on Form (1 sec)
    }
}
```

Now you have **"upcount timer"**.

Remarks:

1. Use `stopwatch.Reset();` to stop timer and reset measured time.
2. Use `stopwatch.Stop();` if you want to stop time measurement, but want to keep meaused time. Similar to "Pause".

Complete `Form` code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // "Upcount Timer"
    private readonly Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    private async void ButtonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stopwatch.Start();

        // Disable START button and enable STOP and PAUSE buttons
        btnStart.Enabled = !(btnPause.Enabled = btnStop.Enabled = true);

        while (stopwatch.IsRunning)
        {
            // Update time in Label on Form
            lblTime.Text = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");
            // Delay between next update
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
    private void ButtonPause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Stop timer, but not reset measured time
        stopwatch.Stop();
        // Enable START button and disable STOP and PAUSE buttons
        btnStart.Enabled = !(btnPause.Enabled = btnStop.Enabled = false);
    }
    private void ButtonStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Stop timer and reset measured time
        stopwatch.Reset();
        
        // Reset time in Label on Form
        lblTime.Text = "00:00:00";
        // or use stopwatch.Elapsed property - after Reset() it would be 00:00:00
        //lblTime.Text = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");
        
        // Enable START button and disable STOP and PAUSE buttons
        btnStart.Enabled = !(btnPause.Enabled = btnStop.Enabled = false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just store the start time in a DateTime and then subtract that from the current time to get a TimeSpan.  With that TimeSpan you can call ToString() and specify whatever format you want.

Something like:

```
DateTime startDT;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timerXD.Interval = 1000;
    timerXD.Enabled = false;
}
private void startstreamBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "00:00:00";
    startDT = DateTime.Now;
    timerXD.Start();
}
private void timerXD_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String elapsed = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startDT).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
    label1.Text = elapsed; // display elapsed somehow
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a seperate Task that cancels when you click the button using a CancellationToken
Right below your class name you can put this:

```
public CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource { get; set; }
    public CancellationToken cancellationToken => this.cancellationTokenSource.Token;
```

Your timer Task can look something like this:

```
private async Task Timer()
    {
        CancellationToken cancel = this.cancellationToken;
        int s = 0;


        TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(s);
        while(!cancel.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            lbltimer.Text = ts.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            s++;
            ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(s);
        }
    }
```

**Now for the Buttons**

Put this in your StartBtn Function

```
cancellationTokenSource = new();
        Timer();
```

and this in your StopBtn Function

```
cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
```

Comment: and if you want to reset the timer you can just do `lbltimer.Text = "00:00:00" `